# Issue regarding quicksort (java)

Tags: java, arrays, quicksort

I'm trying to implement several different types of quicksort in java, but none of my implementations seem to be working. I've looked all over the internet and my code looks very similar to all the code that i've found, so I have no idea whats wrong. My code is as follows: (Note that this isn't complete but I figure if I find whats wrong with one quicksort, the other versions will work as well) Edit: The problem i'm having is that the array doesn't sort correctly. I run a simple method called isSorted to tell me whether the array was sorted correctly. It works with other sorting methods (insertion sort, heap sort etc.) but reports false when used with my implementation of quicksort

```
public static void quickSort(int[] A) {
        flag=0;
        quickSortHelper(A, 0, A.length-1);
    }

public static void quickSortHelper(int [] A, int low, int high){
        if(low<high){
            if(flag==0){
            int q=DPartition(A, low,high,A[high]);
            quickSortHelper(A,low,q-1);
            quickSortHelper(A,q+1,high);
        }

public static int DPartition(int [] A, int low, int high,int pivot){
        int p=pivot;
        int i=low;
        int j=high-1;
        while (i<=j){
            while(i<=j && A[i]<=p){
                i=i+1;
            }
            while(j>=i && A[j]>=p){
                j=j-1;
            }
            if (i<j){
            int temp = A[i];
            A[i] = A[j];
            A[j] = temp;
            }

        }
      int temp = A[i];
      A[i] = A[p];
      A[p] = temp;
      return i;
    }
```

Comment: Your code appears to have unbalanced braces. Does it even compile for you?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: I'm aware there are a couple missing braces. My apologies. These are somewhere later in the code. The code does compile and run, but has some logic error since the array doesn't sort correctly. I'm thinking its a logic error. But I don't really have a stellar understanding of quciksort and I don;t know where the logic error lies

Comment: try posting the actual error or problem you are getting.

Comment: what i would suggest is try looking at other code you found and debug it in Eclipse to see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bug is in your `DPartition` method. In quick sort, you move in a particular direction, and as soon as swapping is performed, you change the direction you move. But, in the above code, you are moving in both the direction without swapping.

The first inner-while loop finds the location of swap, but instead of swapping, you started with the next inner-while, which starts moving in opposite direction. That is faulty.

You should maintain one more variable to store the direction in the array.

You can try modifying your code like this (Not Tested): -

```
// No need to pass `pivot` as parameter. Just use `high`.
public static int DPartition(int [] A, int low, int high) {  
    int i=low;
    int j=high;
    boolean leftToRight = false;
    boolean rightToLeft = true;

    while (i <= j) {   // Iterate till middle

        if (leftToRight) {  // Move left to right

            while(i <= j && A[i] <= A[j]){
                i=i+1;  // Move right until condition is satisfied
            }
            if (i < j) {   // If `i` has not moved beyond `j`. Perform Swap
                swap(i, j, A);   // Pass index for swapping along with array.
            }
            leftToRight = false;   // Toggle to change direction.
            rightToLeft = true;

        } else if (rightToLeft) {  // Move right to left.

            while(j >= i && A[j] >= A[i]){
                j=j-1;
            }
            if (j > i) {    // If j has not moved beyond `i`. Perform Swap
                swap(i, j, A);
            }
            rightToLeft = false;   // Toggle to change the direction
            leftToRight = true;
        } 
    }
    return i;   // Return `index` to split.
}

public static void swap(int p, int q, int[] a) {
    System.out.println("p = " + p + ", q = " + q);
    int temp = a[p];
    a[p] = a[q];
    a[q] = temp;
}
```

Comment: How exactly would I go about fixing that?

Comment: @user979616.. Added the code for your `DPartition` method.